# Automatically build .apk from someone else's github repository

Tags: continuous-integration

I am looking for a tool/service that allows for the following to be done:
given a public repository of an open source Android app (say Signal), I want an automatic tool to build the .apk for me, and then send it to my phone. This is useful so that I don't have to waste time building myself, plus I don't have to be on my computer to build. Also, if the tool builds with every new commit, I am always up to date.

Is there any such tool? Or is there a way of using a combination of services in order to achieve that? Like, if I were to fork the repository, and set up something that keeps it up-to-date every 30minutes, would that make it easier for me to find a service that automatically generates and sends the .apks to my phone?

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about Continuous Integration. There are several tools out which can do the job. A pretty famous and open source solution would be Jenkins. https://jenkins.io
For Jenkins you need an own server.
Beside that you can also find several online tools for that.
For example Buildkite. https://buildkite.com

These tools can not send you the apk directly, but if you combine them with services like hockeyapp (https://hockeyapp.net/) or fabric (https://get.fabric.io/) you can add that functionality in your build process.
It could be also possible to send your apk to a dropbox or a google drive folder if you wish.

Comment: Yeah, needing my own server is the reason why I didn't want to use Jenkins. I was looking for something that works on the cloud (someone else's cloud)..

Comment: Ok, got it. Then you have to try some online tools. I've made good experiences with buildkite. You can also try https://circleci.com/ or https://www.genymotion.com/cloud/ or https://www.bitrise.io/ or https://www.buddybuild.com/. Depends on what you exactly want.